# How to debug "TypeError: A promise cannot be resolved with itself"

Tags: javascript, debugging, asynchronous, es6-promise

In javascripts webconsole in my browser I read the Error message:

`TypeError: A promise cannot be resolved with itself`

which however does not furnish a source code line number or other reference, giving me trouble to even now where that type Error occurs. In all honesty debuging asynchronous things (as are par excellence Promises) turns out to be a challeng. Any idea how I can track down, what and where this TypeError happens?

What I have done is to be able to provoke the same error message 
using this code:

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
    resolve(promise);
  },0);
});
```

But this does only confirm that such a thing as resolving
a promise with itself is indeed something that can occur
and which leads subsequenty to the promise being rejected
due to the occuring error;

```
console.log(promise);
// prints: Promise { <state>: "rejected" }
```

An ideal answer would provide some sort of guide (steps)
that help to show which part of the javascript source code
is actually causes the error.

A helpful answer could also list simply all the ways (other
than the one I have provided example code for) that can lead
to the very same error.

**Updated**
The only place in the source, where a `new Promise(callback)` occurs looks like this, and appears to me cannot cause a circular pattern.

```
function xhrGet(url){    
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{    
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
        xhr.open("GET",url);    
        xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";    
        xhr.addEventListener("load",function(){    
            resolve(xhr.response);    
        });    

        xhr.addEventListener("error",function(er){    
            reject(er);    
        });    
        xhr.send();    
    });    
}
```

It seems imho, unlikely to be the culprit.

here a screenshot of the console output of the debug window of Firefox(ver 68) showing that it sadly **does not always** show the line number

[image: the line number is n o t alwyas shown]

Comment: Errors always contain the line were they occured.

Comment: Regarding your update, of course it doesn't happen only with the promise constructor, but anywhere you resolve a promise. Another example is `const p = ….then(() => { return p })`

Comment: @JonasWilms It seems to not show the line numbers of Errors always. That is why I was prompted to seek help to debug the error. You are positive that there should always be a line number? If so do you consider the absence sort of a "bug"?

Comment: @Bergi Yeah! thank you Bergi your construct, allowed me to spot the place (even without the line number provided in the error message). the `p` in your example is by virtue of deferred asynchronous execution really *a self-reference*.

Answer (score 2):

When `resolve` in a Promise constructor is called with a *different* `Promise`, the value that the constructed Promise resolves to will be what that Promise passed into `resolve` resolves to.

```js
const existingProm = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('existing promise resolving');
    resolve();
  }, 2000);
});

var secondPromise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("second promise's resolve being called");
    resolve(existingProm);
  },1000);
});
secondPromise.then(() => {
  console.log('second promise fulfilled');
});
```

As you can see in the above snippet, although `secondPromise`'s `resolve` is called after 1000 ms, the `secondPromise` only actually resolves after 2000 ms, because `existingProm` (which resolves after 2000 ms) was passed to the `resolve`.

It's just like returning a Promise from inside a `.then` - the *next* `.then` will resolve to the value of what the returned Promise resolved to.

But if you pass the Promise you're constructing to the same `resolve` that's being used to construct the Promise, you've created a cycle - `resolve(promise);` will mean that the constructed Promise resolves only once `promise` resolves. But `promise` *is* that constructed Promise. The interpreter sees this circular situation and throws an error (by rejecting the Promise).

Any sort of circular Promise cycle can result in this error. For example, if `prom1` calls its `resolve` with `prom2`, and `prom2` calls its `resolve` with `prom1`:

```js
const prom1 = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('prom1 resolve being called');
    resolve(prom1);
  }, 1000);
});
const prom2 = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('prom2 resolve being called');
    resolve(prom2);
  }, 1000);
});

prom1.catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
```

To debug an error like this, look at the Promise that generates the error, and examine what its `resolve` was called with, or what was returned from the `.then` that created the Promise. You have a circular chain in there somewhere. For example:

```js
const prom1 = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('prom1 resolve being called');
    resolve(prom1);
  }, 1000);
});
const prom2 = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('prom2 resolve being called');
    resolve(prom2);
  }, 1000);
});

prom1.catch((e) => console.dir(e.stack));
```

On my machine, this shows the error as occurring

> at https://stacksnippets.net/js:16:5

which corresponds to this line:

```
resolve(prom1);
```

which is indeed the source of the circular dependency for `prom1`.

Comment: I think the OP is clear on *why* this happens. He's asking for how to find the offending code in a larger codebase.

Comment: @Bergi you are right, but the answer is already helpful, as it provides another, less direct path to the same error via a prom1->prom2->promi1 circle. Therefore I already appreciate that aspect of the answer, while as you mention hope to find a way to track down which code line introduces the error. I suspect this might be challenging question, as the original cause cicle, could be closed at various places.

Comment: "look at the Promise that generates the error", indeed that is what I would do, but since there is more than one promise in the code and the TypeError message does not pinpoint to any place either. So to some extend the critical aspect of the question is to find out where in the code the loop occurs, more than that it occurs.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace As the other comment said, errors should contain the line number that caused the problem, so you can look at the line indicated and see what the `resolve` there is called with.